# Sends SMS link without a preview in messaging app

Tags: android, ios, sms, twilio

So, from what I've seen people have been doing dots to stop the site image preview:
-'This is my message .https://mylink.com/.'

Now this seems to work on iOS and it filters it, but on android google messaging app it doesn't work. I still get the previews.
On my note default messaging app it works, but it shows the dots. Any other good ideas to stop the preview.

We also shorten the link and track when someone clicks on it, so if it loads the preview it shows up as a click and the preview image sometimes we can't control, so we don't want to show it.

Comment: that is not something you can control, as it is the logic of the messaging app, not yourth

Comment: Yeah, it's not ever going to be 100% just looking for some tricks